# AWS Boto output to a json file

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto

I have to use boto because not all employees have access to CLI or they do not know how to use CLI. It seems like boto is a guess game as I do not see the result of API call that I make with boto. Following is an example,

```
groups=autoscale_connection.get_all_groups()
print groups
```

using AWS CLI you can get output in a JSON file that you can parse easily

However it would be great if we can store output in a json file and then I can look at it and operate on the data I have in file.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work?

```
from boto.ec2.autoscale import AutoScaleConnection
conn = AutoScaleConnection()
git_em = conn.get_all_groups()
print git_em
```

If you have your .boto and other config files set to be json, it should pop right out.

Answer (score 0):

In python,the dictionary data structure is equivalent to a JSON object.

If there exits, you should get a **list** of AG's as per your code(Note: get_all_groups returns a list). Then you just need to convert the list to dict, as per your requirement.

Say to create a map like:

```
AG(keys) -> Description(value) It's easy in python if you explore.
```